# What is the difference between corePoolSize and maxPoolSize in the Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have to send out massEmails to all users of a website. I want to use a thread pool for each email that is sent out. Currently I have set the values to :

```
<property name="corePoolSize" value="500" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="1000" />
```

What is the difference between the two and will it scale. Currently I have approx. 10000 users.

Comment: I take you mean "a thread for each email", not "a thread pool for each email"

Answer (score 67):

Here are Sun’s rules for thread creation in simple terms:

1. If the number of threads is less than the `corePoolSize`, create a new Thread to run a new task.
2. If the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the `corePoolSize`, put the task into the queue.
3. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is less than the `maxPoolSize`, create a new thread to run tasks in.
4. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is greater than or equal to `maxPoolSize`, reject the task.

[Full article](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size)

[Origin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660048/threadpoolexecutor-core-and-maximum-pool-sizes/35028992#35028992)

Comment: So, could you explain this strange behavior in this `ThreadExecutor` [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253164/threadpoolexecutor-with-corepoolsize-0-should-not-execute-tasks-until-task-queue). It is not following the 4 cases you mentioned here.

Answer (score 50):

[The javadoc says it best](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> When a new
>   task is submitted [...], and
>   fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are
>   running, a new thread is created to
>   handle the request, even if other
>   worker threads are idle. If there are
>   more than `corePoolSize` but less than
>   `maximumPoolSize` threads running, a
>   new thread will be created only if the
>   queue is full. By setting
>   `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize`
>   the same, you create a fixed-size
>   thread pool. By setting
>   `maximumPoolSize` to an essentially
>   unbounded value such as
>   `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you allow the
>   pool to accommodate an arbitrary
>   number of concurrent tasks.

As for your specific situation, sending 500 emails all at the same time is pointless, you'll just overwhelm the mail server. If you need to send a large number of emails, then use a single thread, and send them down the pipe one at a time. The mail server will handle this much more gracefully than 500 separate connections.

Comment: I am not able to see this happening in this `ThreadExecutor` [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253164/threadpoolexecutor-with-corepoolsize-0-should-not-execute-tasks-until-task-queue). Can you explain what's different here?

Answer (score 23):

`corePoolSize` is the minimum number of threads used by the pool. The number can increase up to `maxPoolSize`. When the load goes down, the pool will shrink back to `corePoolSize`.

Sending email seems to be an I/O bound operation. I do not think having 500 threads will make it faster.

Answer (score 13):

We already have so many answers and would suffice, but I always confused every other day. So I came up with a real time example to relate this!

A simple and efficient way to get this is by considering yourself being in a bank.

You ever stood in a line even though there is a window available?
Why would the bank keep a customer in a queue if there are available cash-window? That's exactly the case with `core pool size`. If there are un-used threads, new tasks are directly allocated to them.

[image]

One the available window(core pool size) is full, customers are asked to wait in the queue. This is where the `queue-capacity` comes in picture! New tasks are keep on queueing until no more tasks can be queued.

[image]

What if the wait-lounge is full of customers? Bank can allocate/open new cash-windows as they see spike in number of customers(tasks). They had 3 more in reserve.
Here comes the `max pool size` in context.

Once these windows(threads) are all occupied, Bank can no longer server any new customers(tasks). Agree? And henceforth, new tasks are not accepted!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @skaffman pointed out from [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), following also makes it more clear how these sizes are utilized:

Any `BlockingQueue` may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:

- If fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are running, the `Executor` always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
- If `corePoolSize` or more threads are running, the `Executor` always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
- If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed `maximumPoolSize`, in which case, the task will be rejected.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider to increase value of **queueCapacity** than consider to increase value of **corePoolSize** or **maxPoolSize**. Those two properties (*PoolSize) are number of pool to execute but each message would be considering in *queueCapacity*

```
<property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
<property name="queueCapacity" value="1000" />
<property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
```

If you have 10000 users to send so 1000 * 10 (maxPoolSize) = 10000 but if 1000 for each thread is heavy, we can consider to increase poolSize.

Comment: Queue capacity is at Integer.MAX_VALUE by default, so no need to increase it!

Comment: @rlm, in that case, no more threads will be created and thread will remain at `corePoolSize`.

Comment: @rlm. This contradicts the answer by @taynguyen? According to that answer, a new thread will only be created if queue is full.

Comment: @BillMan, answer of taynguyen is sun implementation but developer who ask the question talks about "Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor". In "Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor", queue capacity is initialized at integer max value and max pool size too so that "allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks (skaffman)"

Comment: @rlm: The default configuration is a core pool size of 1, with unlimited max pool size and unlimited queue capacity. This is roughly equivalent to Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Comment: @Pant & @BillMan are right. In my experience too, by default in Spring `corePoolSize` will be the maximum number of threads created as default queue capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

What everyone has explained so clearly is correct. Few things to notice here is that you should always have a limited size for core-pool as well as queue. If the core-pool-size if very high, there can a high chance that many of your threads from pool are remaining unused for certain period of time since for every request new thread gets created until it reaches max-pool-size

But if your machine is going to face large number of request concurrently then you should also consider that the machine size is sufficient enough : example:

If your machine size in 1 GB and queue capacity is at Integer.MAX_VALUE then there is a high chance that your machine will start rejecting the requesting at some point of time because of OutOfMemory which you can monitor in any JVM GUI tool.