# How to decide corePoolSize of an Executor

Tags: java, executorservice

How someone should decide `corePoolSize` of an `Executor`? In many application I have seen Executors with corePoolSize 5. I understand it depends upon the requirement. But requirements are not the single parameter for it. Hardware like RAM Processors also matters. Are there any thumb rules for it?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659510/core-pool-size-vs-maximum-pool-size-in-threadpoolexecutor)

Comment: It does not answer my question properly. Suppose I am writing
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100). Initiating a poolsize with 100 does not make any sense. So how to choose a value for pool size while creating an Execotor?