# ThreadPoolExecutor - Core and maximum pool sizes

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

> When a new task is submitted in method `execute(java.lang.Runnable)`,and fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.

1) Why there is a need to create a new thread to handle the request if there are idle threads?

> If there are more than `corePoolSize` but less than `maximumPoolSize` threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.

2) I don't understand the difference between `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` here. Secondly, how can a queue be full when threads are less than `maximumPoolSize`? Queue can only be full if threads are equal to or more than `maximumPoolSize`. Isn't it?

Comment: 1.  How does execute() know that your other worker threads are idle?  Have you returned them back to the pool when you are done with them?

Comment: 2.  It sounds like the ThreadPoolExecutor is trying to maintain a pool of usable threads larger than corePoolSize but smaller than maximumPoolSize.

Comment: @RobertHarvey please post this as an answer.

Comment: @zEro: I'm not a Java expert.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259906/5324721

Answer (score 30):

Here are Sun’s rules for thread creation in simple terms:

1. If the number of threads is less than the corePoolSize, create a new Thread to run a new task.
2. If the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the corePoolSize, put the task into the queue.
3. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is less than the maxPoolSize, create a new thread to run tasks in.
4. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is greater than or equal to maxPoolSize, reject the task.

[Full article](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size)

Comment: This is by far the most clear and concise description of what gets done. Thank you so much for this clear explanation.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the definition of the terms corepoolsize and maxpoolsize in the javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

The link above has the answer to your question. However, just to make it clear. The application will creating threads until it reaches the corePoolSize. It means that these number of threads should be sufficient to handle the inflow of tasks. After that the tasks will be queued. Once the queue is full the executor will start creating new threads. It is kind of balancing. What it essentially means is that the inflow of tasks is more than the processing capacity. So, Executor will start creating new threads again till it reaches Max number of threads. Again, a new threads will be created if and only if the queue is full.

Answer (score 7):

***Core and maximum pool sizes***

A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size  according to the bounds set by corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize .

When a new task is submitted in method `execute(java.lang.Runnable)`, and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool.

By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using `setCorePoolSize(int)` and `setMaximumPoolSize(int)`. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: Please try to format your answer to improve readability.