# Understanding poolSize in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I glanced at `execute` method of `ThreadPoolExecutor` class. This seems to be very short and simple:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (poolSize >= corePoolSize || !addIfUnderCorePoolSize(command)) {
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        }
        else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to be happening if the the condition `poolSize >= corePoolSize` is satisfied!

Because of if the first part of a `OR`condition is true, the second won't be executed:

```
if (true || anyMethodWillNotBeExecuted()) { ... }
```

According to [the rules for thread creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35028992/4898850), here also is `maximumPoolSize`. And in case if the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the `corePoolSize` and less than `maxPoolSize` the new thread should be created for task or task should be added to queue.

So why in case when `poolSize` greater than or equals to `corePoolSize` nothing should happen?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addIfUnderCorePoolSize` will create a new "core" thread for this executor.
If number of threads in the executor (`poolSize`) is already greater than or equal to number of "core" threads (`corePoolSize`), then obviously there is no need to create more "core" threads.

Maybe expanding `OR` condition will be a bit clearer:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (poolSize >= corePoolSize) {
        // there are enough core threads
        // let's try to put task on the queue
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        } else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    } else if (addIfUnderCorePoolSize(command)) {
        // there was not enough core threads, so we started one
        // the task is being executed on a new thread, so there's nothing else to be done here
        return;
    } else {
        // there are enough core threads
        // but we could not start a new thread
        // so let's try to add it to the queue
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        } else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    }
}
```

Comment: But here also is `maximumPoolSize`. And in case if the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the `corePoolSize` and less than `maxPoolSize` the new thread should be created or task should be added to queue. ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/35028992/4898850

Comment: yes, that's what happens here. Could you please explain which part is not clear?

Comment: What does mean `poolSize` at all?.. Should this value be checked in comparison with `corePoolSize` and `maxPoolSize`, isn't it? So why is it checked only in comparison with `corePoolSize`, not with `maxPoolSize`?

Comment: `poolSize` is the number of created threads in the executor. I assume it is compared against `maxPoolSize` inside `addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was something with my eyes and brains. Thank you, you are right! :)